Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0' obsolete
I received this message in the mailbox of Google Play Console :

androidx.annotation has reported that version 1.0.0 of the SDK is obsolete.
Consider upgrading to a more recent version (1.0.1 - 1.0.2, 1.1.0-alpha02+).
These versions have not been reviewed by Google Play.
It is possible that they may contain vulnerabilities or fail to comply with our policies.
Carefully assess third-party SDKs before integrating them into your app.

I do not have direct link of 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0' in build.gradle.
However a large number of librairies we use includes 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
Like picasso:2.71828 on the first level.
    +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828  
    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0  

Or androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1 on the 3rd level
    +--- androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1    
    |    +--- androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5  
    |    |    +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.0.1 -> 2.1.0  
    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0  

I first have an important question :
What is the exact manipulation to find the list of dependencies (containing annotation:1.0.0) that will eventually be a problem when my app bundle is uploaded to google console ?
Indeed, when i type this command "./gradlew app:dependencies" it gives me all the lists concerning every type of build, even intermediate builds (and the lists are all different). But is it relevant ?
I mean that when I look at the list concerning the release apk ("releaseRuntimeClasspath") the list of dependencies (and its resolutions) is really smaller, especially concerning "annotation:1.0.0".
So, considering these differencies in the lists, I really don't know on which to apply the corrections needed.
Then, what are my options to resolve the issues ?
Thank you
PS: If needed, i can put a sample of my dependency tree
I tried to exclude for picasso,
    implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828') {
        exclude group: 'androidx.annotation'
    }

but the obsolete version seems to stay when i launch again the command
Also I used
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    }

But is it really a good practice ? Will Picasso still run correctly ?
